# Apply EQ Settings on MPMusicPlayerController

Tags: ios, xcode, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am trying to play iPod music library songs using the `MPMusicPlayerController`, it is working fine. Now I am trying to apply EQ Settings using the `MPMusicPlayerController`. I have been searching for it for one week but I couldn't find any solution. Any ideas/suggestions/notes would be very helpful. I have seen the EQ settings in the **MyTunes Pro app by SRS**.

Comment: Did you ever find anything out here?